# Integrating GSL with Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, gsl

I am trying to get Xcode 5.1.1 to find the headers of GSL. My ideal solution would be one that would  allow me to access these headers on all future projects with no extra work (automagically if you will). Most instructions seem to say to add the library path under the project's Build Setting -> Search Path section, however, my project does not seem to have a library or header option there. I have also tried to use the Link Binary with Libraries under the Build Phases tab, but /usr/local/include is "invisible" and I am reluctant to move these headers from their install location (unless this is normal/acceptable). Lastly I have tried to edit the Source Trees preference to add the library path, but this does not seem to work either. I wouldn't be surprised if I was doing that last part incorrectly as I am rather confused about the proper way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution works on Xcode 5.1

In the side view click on your project, there should be a tab that can either be set to "Basic" or "All," select "All." Under the subsection labeled "Linking" there should be a field called "Other Linkers" enter these flags:

-I/usr/local/include
-L/usr/local/lib
-lgsl
-lgslcblas