# Link C++ Library in Xcode [Mac]

Tags: c++, xcode, gsl

First of all, I am completely new to C++. What I have:

1. Mac
2. Installed Xcode

Thats it. No prior knowledge about anything Xcode/C++ related.
I need to use a few functions from [GSL library](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/), to run a code for my project. What I did:

1. From GSL library site I [downloaded](http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/gnu/gsl/) a file called "gsl-latest.tar.gz".
2. Moved it to my C++ folder on desktop and unpacked it.(attached screenshoot of unpacked folder and what it includes)
3. Created an Xcode project by: Xcode -> create a new project -> command line.
4. Opened a file for this project which contains functions from mentioned library.

I know that in order to use functions I have to include them, i.e:

```
#include <gsl/gsl_randist.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_rng.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_sf_gamma.h>
```

But before "including" functions, I need to link gsl library to my project. How to do it?

Help.

[image]

Comment: `brew install gsl`

Comment: @S.M. I already did it, but functions still don't work. Brew gives me this: "Warning: gsl 2.6 is already installed and up-to-date", so its ok here.

Comment: Nice. Then follow [Integrating GSL with Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25983405/6752050). Although the answer is old enough, the information there is still actual.